# I plugged in a Space Heater to my outlet, now my outlet doesn't work. Power still on

Tags: electrical

I'm a college kid living in my first house (not dorm) who knows absolutely nothing about electrical systems. I found the breaker box(?) in the back yard but have no idea what I would have to flip to even troubleshoot. Any help would be appreciated. The problem is summarized in the title.

In addition to my specific outlet not working, an outlet in an adjacent room also doesn't work. I still have power and just moved my PC to another outlet.

Comment: A picture of the breaker box in the back yard may help.  Open the door so we can see the breakers

Comment: If you are renting this house, do not mess with the wiring. You can reset a breaker, but that is it. If you do ANYTHING to the wiring, and then there is a fire you could be held responsible. Contact the landlord.

Answer (score 2):

Check for a tripped breaker, not always obvious, but usually are.   If the panel is properly labeled, try turning off the breaker for the problematic circuit and then back on again, if that fixes the problem, you're good to go and don't use that space heater on the same circuit again!

**EDIT:  An excellent comment below which needs to be repeated here:  If you are renting the house, this is a landlord problem and you should limit your activities to resetting breakers.**

If no breakers tripped and  resetting them just in case didn't fix the problem,  you probably have a blown back stab outlet.   They are notorious for failing under heavy loads.

Since you said you have no electrical experience, A quick lesson:  Back stabs are a colloquial term used in electrical trades for outlets that to install, all you had to do was strip the ends of the wires and poke them in the back of the outlets (back stab). The actual connection was very tiny and prone to failure, esp. under heavy loads like a space heater.

What you need to do is get a voltage tester, find the breaker that controls the recalcitrant circuit, be sure, using your voltage tester that the power is actually off, and start pulling out outlets, looking for damage like burn marks, melted plastic, etc.

Best practice to put them back together is to pig tail the connection (power in, power out, power to the outlet via the pig tail wire-nutted together, blacks to blacks and whites to whites).  That way you don't count on the outlet itself to serve down stream outlets.

Be careful here, while this is a DIY site, it's up to you if you're comfortable doing this, if not, while we don't like saying this here, you might need to call a pro.

Comment: I want to use all caps to say this, but will try to restrain myself. If you are renting, do not under any circumstances start taking outlets apart. Seriously. Just flip all the breakers off and on. If that doesn't fix it, call the landlord.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Absolutely a a great point. When the OP said he was living in his "first house" I assumed he was the owner, stupid assumption.   Thanks for pointing this out. I'm going to edit my answer to include your excellent comment. +

Comment: I'll repeat it, just to be sure: YOU ARE RENTING. DO **_NOT_** DO REPAIRS YOURSELF. It's illegal for you _or_ the landlord to do repairs. He _must_ hire a licensed electrician.

Comment: @FreeMan The OP hasn't confirmed he is renting, but it's likely.

Comment: True, but _most_ college kids don't own. Mom & dad may have purchased the house, however, and he may have permission. It is, however, worth emphasizing the point for this asker and future readers.

Comment: @FreeMan  Yeah, we just don't know yet, hopefully the OP will respond.  I know of a family with 5 kids, fairly spread apart in age.  They bought a house in a college town, sent all the kids to the same college/university, also rented to some roomies, then when the youngest graduated, sold the house at a huge profit and never had to pay room and board for their kids, brilliant.  But I'm getting conversational now and don't want to get snipped by the moderators!  Bottom line:  We don't know who owns the house yet.